# Linq to Xml is printing only first descendant value

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

The following code is printing `Building Phone` but not printing `uxPhone`. 

1) Should I be getting a collection of `Property` descendants maybe?

2) This seems pretty verbose, is there a shorter form of doing this?

```
var xmlstr =
        @"<Form>
        <ControlsLayout>
        <Object type='sometype' children='Controls'>
        <Property name='ControlLabel'>BuildingPhone</Property>
        <Property name='Name'>uxPhone</Property>
        </Object>
        </ControlsLayout>
        </Form>";

XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xmlstr);      
var controls = xelement.Descendants("Object");
foreach (var control in controls)
{
    var xElement = control.Element("Property");
    if (xElement != null)
    {
        var xAttribute = xElement.Attribute("name");
        if (xAttribute != null && xAttribute.Value == "ControlLabel")
            { Console.WriteLine(xElement.Value); }
            if (xAttribute != null && xAttribute.Value == "Name")
            { Console.WriteLine(xElement.Value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mostafiz and Gilad. I will mark one of you answered and the other a upvote. Gilad your code didnt work for me because of a 6.0 language feature? Any chance you can rework it for 4.5 (is max we can go in prod) It would be a bonus if you explain the 6.0 feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be getting a collection of Property descendants maybe?

The use of the `Element` function in `control.Element("Property")` returns a single element. You want instead to use `Elements`.

> This seems pretty verbose, is there a shorter form of doing this?

A nicer way all together is to use `Descendants("Property")` (which searches recursively in your xml and returns the collection of elements of the `<>` you specified)  and instead of `if` statements to use a `where` clause:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xmlstr);
var result = from element in xelement.Descendants("Property")
             let attribute = element.Attribute("name")
             where (attribute != null && attribute.Value == "ControlLabel" )||
                   (attribute != null && attribute.Value == "Name" )
             select element.Value;

foreach(var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

// Building Phone
// uxPhone
```

Comment: Gilad see my comment on the OP.

Comment: @bkolluru - See fix. BTW - if you found both answers useful you can upvote both. And then still mark one of them as the one that solved

Comment: @bkolluru - glad that it helped you :)

Comment: Thanks Gilad, this works great and also satisfies question (2) that I had asked! I marked it answered. For other reading this, the only change I made is to do <br> from element in controls.Descendants("Property")<br> ControlsLayout/Object? After all element "Property" could be descendant elswhere, outside of ControlsLayout.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `control.Element("Property")` which select single one, use `control.Elements("Property")` which select all with `Property`

```
 XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xmlstr);
 //var controls = xelement.Descendants("ControlsLayout");
 var controls = xelement.Descendants("Object");
 foreach (var control in controls)
 {
    var xElement = control.Elements("Property"); // change this line
    foreach (var element in xElement)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            var xAttribute = element.Attribute("name");
            if (xAttribute != null && xAttribute.Value == "ControlLabel")
            { Console.WriteLine(element.Value); }
            if (xAttribute != null && xAttribute.Value == "Name")
            { Console.WriteLine(element.Value); }
        }
    }

 }
```