# Extract values from XML with linq query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

New to linq and XML and looking for a way to return values of
`<AddtlInf></AddtlInf>` as a list which I will then concatenate the values to a single string.

XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<Document xmlns='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <CstmrPmtStsRpt>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>21233519</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2018-11-29T09:28:00</CreDtTm>
      <InitgPty>
        <Nm>Standard Bank SA</Nm>
        <Id>
          <OrgId>
            <BICOrBEI>SBZAZAJJXXX</BICOrBEI>
          </OrgId>
        </Id>
      </InitgPty>
    </GrpHdr>
    <OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
      <OrgnlMsgId>Domestic Base-612742-300749</OrgnlMsgId>
      <OrgnlMsgNmId>PAIN.001.001.03</OrgnlMsgNmId>
      <OrgnlCreDtTm>2018-11-29T12:23:06</OrgnlCreDtTm>
      <OrgnlNbOfTxs>1</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
      <OrgnlCtrlSum>17500.00</OrgnlCtrlSum>
      <GrpSts>RJCT</GrpSts>
      <StsRsnInf>
        <Rsn>
          <Cd>NARR</Cd>
        </Rsn>
        <AddtlInf>Duplicate File</AddtlInf>
        <AddtlInf>Error: 6789</AddtlInf>
        <AddtlInf>Not Processed</AddtlInf>
      </StsRsnInf>
    </OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
  </CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

So far I have:

```
var info = doc.Descendants(ns + "CstmrPmtStsRpt")
           .Descendants(ns + "OrgnlGrpInfAndSts")
           .Descendants(ns + "StsRsnInf")                                       
           .Select(r => new
           {
                Info = r.Element(ns + "AddtlInf").Value                                          
           }).ToList();
```

But this only returns "Duplicate File", the first value. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the sub-elements of `StsRsnInf`:

```
var info = doc.Descendants(ns + "CstmrPmtStsRpt")
            .Descendants(ns + "OrgnlGrpInfAndSts")
            .Descendants(ns + "StsRsnInf")                                       
            .SelectMany(r => r.Elements(ns + "AddtlInf").Select(s => new
            {
              Info = s.Value
            })).ToList();
```

By using `Element`(without trailing s), you only access a single element instead of several, hence your result does only contain the value of the first element.

By using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) as opposed to `Select` you can return several elements from sub-enumerations.

Comment: Simple and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `r.Element` will always return you the first element of the collection.
Instead try to use `r.Elements`, which will return you the collection of "AddtlInf" elements.

For detailed information about this, have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40135859/linq-to-xml-is-printing-only-first-descendant-value)!

Answer (score 0):

You may use [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.7.2) in Linq.

```
var result = (string)xdoc.Descendants("member")
                         .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Element("name") == "responseCode")
                         ?.Element("value");

    var info = xdoc.Descendants("CstmrPmtStsRpt")
   .Descendants("OrgnlGrpInfAndSts")
   .Descendants("StsRsnInf")                                       
   .SelectMany(r=> r.Descendants("AddtlInf")).ToList();
   Console.WriteLine(info.Count); // prints 3.
```

Dotnet fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/IKd7go

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative this seems easier to me:

```
var list = doc.XPathSelectElements
                ("Document/CstmrPmtStsRpt/OrgnlGrpInfAndSts/StsRsnInf/AddtlInf")
                .Select(n => n.Value);
```